# Regarding Map as user defined base

Tags: java

I have developed a pojo named Employee.java. Now I was planning to make it as user defined collection. I want to make a map and store all the employee type objects in it.

Below is my pojo

```
    public class Employee {     
     String name,job;
     int salary;


     public Employee(String n , String j, int t ) //constructor
     {
         this.name= n;
         this.job=j;
         this.salary= t; 

     } 

     @Override
     public int hashCode()
     {       
         return name.hashCode()+job.hashCode()+salary;       

     }
     @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {  

         Employee e = (Employee) obj;   
         return this.name.equals(e.name)&&this.job.equals(e.job)&&this.salary==e.salary;
     }


}
```

Now I have developed another class that contains map and will store employee type objects..

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
        {           
        Map employeeMap = new HashMap();
        Employee e = new Employee("Saral", "Trainer", 34000);
        Employee e1 = new Employee("Sarall", "saral", 34090);
        employeeMap.put("S", e);
        employeeMap.put("S1", e);
        System.out.println(employeeMap.size());
        Set s = employeeMap.entrySet();

        Iterator it = s.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {           
            Map.Entry m =(Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println(m.getKey()+"\t"+m.getValue());

        }
```

but when I try to run it , I want to fetch the employee details but I GET DISPLAYED THE OBJECT ON SCREEN ...I want to see the employees value, Please advise me how to get values from employee object.

```
2
S   CollectionsPrac.Employee@285c2854
S1  CollectionsPrac.Employee@285c2854
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the `toString` method in your Employee class, for example:

```
public String toString() {
    return name + " [" + job + "] - salary: " + salary;
}
```

By the way, you can replace:

```
    Iterator it = s.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {           
        Map.Entry m =(Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(m.getKey()+"\t"+m.getValue());

    }
```

with

```
System.out.println(s.toString());
```

Unless you really want the output to be tab separated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `toString()` method of Employee

```
@Override pulic String toString() {
    return name + " " + job;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all. Your hashcode is broken.
Try running this:

```
        System.out.println("Should be false: " + (new Employee("Sara", "Trainer", 1).hashCode() == new Employee("Trainer", "Sara", 1).hashCode()));
```

If you are using and IDE (like eclipse) there is a function to generate equals and hashcode methods automatically and you would get something like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((job == null) ? 0 : job.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + salary;
    return result;
}



@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Employee other = (Employee) obj;
    if (job == null) {
        if (other.job != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!job.equals(other.job))
        return false;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    if (salary != other.salary)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

As for your main method.. You should try to learn some basics about generics (the stuff inside the <>). You don't need the nity grity details at first. Just learn how to use it with lists and maps.. It will make your life a lot easier. Especially since your using and IDE...

Here is a refactored version of your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {           
        Map<String, Employee> employeeMap = new HashMap<String, Employee>();
        Employee e = new Employee("Saral", "Trainer", 34000);
        Employee e1 = new Employee("Sarall", "saral", 34090);
        employeeMap.put("S", e);
        employeeMap.put("S1", e1);
        System.out.println(employeeMap.size());
        Set<Entry<String, Employee>> entrySet = employeeMap.entrySet();
        for (Entry<String, Employee> entry: entrySet) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+"\t"+entry.getValue().name);
        }

        System.out.println("Should be false: " + (new Employee("Sara", "Trainer", 1).hashCode() == new Employee("Trainer", "Sara", 1).hashCode()));
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I did not understand how the hashcode() is broken , please expalin in detail..!! I have generated that hashcode() which eclipse generate but how it is different from mine hashcode(), please expalin in detail.

Comment: I have also checked that while using the eclipse one it is coming out false which is perfect but while using mine one it is coming as true, please explain whats wrong in my implementation of hash code() and how it is different from eclipse generated hashcode() and what about if I want to write my own hashcode() for this class, thanks in advance.

Comment: I have never seen eclipse generate your kind of hashcode.. But the problem is that (a+b) = (b+a). So when calculating a hashcode you must take into consideration the order of the fields.. See here for more details: http://www.technofundo.com/tech/java/equalhash.html

Answer (score 0):

Change this in

```
Iterator it = s.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{           
  Map.Entry m =(Map.Entry)it.next();
  Employee empl = (Employee) m.getValue();
  System.out.println(m.getKey()+"\t"+empl.name);
}
```

As you can see with the line

```
Employee empl = (Employee) m.getValue();
```

the value is "casted" to an `Employee` object, and you can start to work with `empl` variable and use all the `Employee` class methods and members.